# Accessing elements of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1|1,2,3
    [2] => 2|2,3,7,11
    [3] => 3|1,2,4,8,12
)
```

It is called `$new_array`

I split the elements of the array using the pipe as follows:

```
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {

    $new_arr = $parsed_item = explode('|',$value);

    print_r($new_arr);

}
```

That gives me three arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1,2,3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2,3,7,11
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1,2,4,8,12
)
```

I can't work out how to access the elements of the `$new_arr` array - for each loop through, I want to access the elements, to write some SQL, so I would end up with:

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET includes = '1,2,3' WHERE id = 1;"
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET includes = '2,3,7,11' WHERE id = 2;"
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET includes = '1,2,4,8,12' WHERE id = 3;"
```

But I can't see how I can access the elements of the `$new_arr` array.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($new_arr as $key2 => $value2) {
    $f1 = $value2[0];
    echo $f1 . "<br>";
}
```

But it outputs this:

```
1
1
2
2
3
1
```

So I guess that isn't correct.

Comment: Change to `$new_arr[] = $parsed_item = explode('|',$value);`

Comment: It is normally a VERY BAD idea putting comma delimited data in a single column as it makes it almost impossile to process it later

Answer (score 0):

The use of comma separated  values is generally discouraged for difficulties in managing this kind  of strings for extracing single values using sql  ..

but anyway
You should add the explode to an array  eg:

```
  foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {

      $new_arr[] = $parsed_item = explode('|',$value);


  }

  print_r($new_arr);
```

then you could use

```
foreach ($new_arr as $key => $value) {
    $f1 = $value[0];
    $f2 = $value[1]
    echo $f1 . "<br>" . $f2 . "<br>" ;
}
```

and so you could use the $value[0]  as  the id column and the $value[1] as the includes  column

Comment: I'm not sure "deprecated" is the word you're looking for here. Did you just mean "discouraged"? Even then, discouraged by who, and under what circumstances? I can see plenty of legitimate reasons you might have data in that form that you need to process.

Comment: @IMSoP  answer  updated  with  (hope ) a better terms  ..  and a brief explain

Comment: I'm surprised with 80K rep you'd bother with answering such questions. /shrugs